# Bash Script which calls osascript stops working when run by launchd

Tags: macos, applescript, bash, launchd

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem with a bash script that gets called  by launchd.  Here's a quick summary

- Calling the script manually by itself works fine with no errors.
- Within the bash script it calls an AppleScript that posts a notification  That AppleScript works fine.
- The `.plist` gets loaded and kicks off at the correct interval and calls the bash script.  So that works properly
- The `.plist` is called from `/Library/LaunchDaemons` (so it can run regardless if anyone is logged in or not).  **This means everything is run as root.**

The problem occurs within the bash script which calls an AppleScript to post a notification - it just never happens.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ------------------------------------------------------------------


sleep 11                           
echo "This is a test" > test.txt   
/usr/bin/osascript /Users/allan/Documents/Scripts/AppleScript/notify.scpt "This is a test" "-Test Test Test" "nosound"

exit 0
```

That's it.  A quick summary of what I am doing:

1. `sleep 11` - launchd needs a min. of 10 seconds of program execution time by default.  I just put this in here to accommodate launchd
2. `echo "This is a test"` - I just write a simple string to a text file to make sure the bash script is getting called.  *This file gets created with the expected string*; this works.
3. `/usr/bin/osascript /Users......blah blah blah...` **this fails**.  This is just a simple AppleScript that takes three arguments (body, title, and sound) to provide a notification.

Running by itself or bash script that calls it, it works:

[image]

When the bash script is called from launchd it seems to just not work.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  What am I missing?

(OS X 10.11.6)

---

This is the `.plist` I am using (yes I know it's set for a 45 second interval...I'm testing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.podcastCleanup</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/allan/Documents/Scripts/Unix/podcastCleanup.sh</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>45</integer>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/allan/Documents</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

Following is the `notify.scpt` AppleScript that is used to generate the notification.

```
on run argv

    set Message to item 1 of argv
    set Title to item 2 of argv
    set aud to item 3 of argv
    set STitle to "Terminal"
    set Snd to "Blow.aiff"


    if (aud = "sound") then

        display notification Message with title Title subtitle STitle sound name Snd
    else
        display notification Message with title Title subtitle STitle
    end if

end run
```

Comment: Please add the scpt and the plist. I'm too lazy to create it!

Comment: No problem to get this running in 10.11.6 as ~/Lib/LaunchAgent - even with sleep set to 1 and StartInterval to 10 without any error. Please check the paths in the plist and is the sh executable?

Comment: As /Lib/LaunchDaemon the launchd error is "osascript[12982:35171] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data"

Comment: @klanomath - Tested as `Library/LaunchAgent` and it works fine, but I need  it to run regardless if I am logged in or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Graphical User Session Required

The error occurs because the commands in your `osascript` require a [graphical user session](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION9). AppleScript requires a graphical user session to work.

The `launchd` job is running as the `root` user in a non-graphical user session.

### Alternative Approach

In these situations, the typical approach is to split daemons in two parts – one computer wide and another within each graphical user session. A pipe or socket is frequently used to communicate.

Even as `root` user, there are barriers that can not be crossed in macOS.

Comment: @Allan to fix it please try to load it from ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

Comment: This makes sense now that you explain it.  Since I need it to run regardless if I am logged in or not, I can't do what @MateuszSzlosek suggested.  What I will do is write the "result" to a text file that will be processed by another script that generates notifications when  I am  logged in...or something to that effect.