# Is there a way to prevent applications to run, like I can with selfControl to disable opening websites?

Tags: macos, applications

I want to force myself to focus.

I use https://selfcontrolapp.com to block websites. How can I block apps?

Is there a utility app, or a terminal command you know?

Comment: Hi Flavio! I think you might find what you need here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334534/is-it-possible-to-allow-usage-for-an-app-or-program-for-a-specific-time-on-mac

Comment: Thank you, I think I found 2 apps that will do the job (answering)

Answer (score 1):

Freedom allows you to block apps on desktop, it includes a locked mode that should work if you block the right things, it is a paid app however.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 apps that can work as apps blockers:

- [Cold Turkey](https://getcoldturkey.com)
- [Focus](https://heyfocus.com)