# Can I change launchd program arguments based on calendar interval?

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm trying to run a script (`zfssnap.sh`) to automate snapshots, but one of the arguments needs to change based on which time entry triggers the script to start. With cron, I would just add a new line with the changed argument and set the time fields accordingly.

In reading the `launchd` and `launchd.conf` man pages, I'm not seeing any way to associate an argument with a specific `StartCalendarInterval` key entry. This seems like a significant limitation, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Is there a way change an argument based on the time the script is being run? Or, do I have to make a new plist for each of the situations I'm trying to satisfy?

Comment: Do it in a bash script that actually changes program arguments.  See this example:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334534/is-it-possible-to-allow-usage-for-an-app-or-program-for-a-specific-time-on-mac/334569#334569

Comment: That might work. I can spread the times a bit to make for a more decisive test.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" thing to do is make a new .plist for each different time/argument combo. This is essentially the equivalent of making multiple entries in the crontab, except that each "entry" is an entire file, not just a line.

There's a good example of this in macOS's launch daemon entries for the periodic maintenance program. /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-daily.plist runs /usr/libexec/periodic-wrapper with the argument "daily" and a 24-hour interval, ...periodic-weekly.plist runs it with the argument "weekly" and a 7-day interval, and ...periodic-monthly.plist runs it with the argument "monthly" and a 30.44-day interval.

Comment: I decided to go this way, but what a PITA. I wish Apple would make this more flexible since they've deprecated cron. In any case, I'm still having trouble getting one of them to work. The argument is `<string>pool/dataset</string>` and I'm thinking `launchd` is treating as a path instead of a simple argument being passed to the script. I may still have to run a separate script for that one.

Comment: @tim.rohrer It should be treated as a plain string, with no interpretation at all applied (it doesn't even expand `~` or wildcards unless you set the `EnableGlobbing` key). Can you tell what the script is receiving as its argument?

Comment: `zxfer` from `https://github.com/allanjude/zxfer`. The launchd status code is 3, which I've not yet been able to find defined. I can take the same command line and arguments from the plist and it appears to run successfully. Here is a pastebin of the plist: https://pastebin.com/VAeGeN4E

Comment: I'm not familiar with `zxfer`, but I don't see anything obviously wrong. One thing to check: do all of the .plists have different `Label` values?

Comment: Yes, as I've made them match the filenames used. Any idea on what code 3 means?

Comment: I'd expect that to be a code from `zxfer`, but its man page says "exits 0 on success, 1 on an error and 2 if a command line option is incorrect"... so I don't know. Try adding `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys (pointing to reasonable log locations) so you can see if it's printing any helpful errors. Also, check /var/log/system.log for messages from launchd (although I'm not sure it still sends anything useful there).

Comment: I did not know the exit status code could/would be from the script/command being run. I’ll dig into the script; will try tomorrow. Thanks.