# how to add a sound notification to an app that doesn't have one?

Tags: audio, notifications

I use an app to copy and log video files that only has a silent notification and I'd like to add a sound to the notification. my thought was that maybe there is a third party app like keyboard maestro that could trigger an sound action from my app's notification, but I don't think that is possible.

Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround?

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/257541/119271) for sn rxample on how you can create your own notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences and there is a Notification Icon in the top row. Click on this and you'll get an image like the one shown below.

[image]

Click on your app in the left column and click the 'Play Sound for Notification' box on the right side of this pane.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, unfortunately the app i’m using doesn’t have a sound notification. The option you mentioned is there however no sound plays upon a notification. I’m looking for a work around.

Comment: Geez, sorry. I don't know why it doesn't.